# How to get default playback device ID through winapi on C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, audio

I'd like to get a default audio device ID through WinAPI with C#. I wish to save this ID (and volume also in the future) for restoring it in the future in WinServer2012 and Windows8. I try to avoid any wrappers or inclusions of additional dll. As I googled it is possible with the following WinAPI function:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern uint waveOutMessage(IntPtr deviceID, uint uMsg, ref uint dwParam1, ref uint dwParam2);
```

I've found an example to call following functions:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern uint waveOutMessage(IntPtr deviceID, uint uMsg, IntPtr dwParam1, IntPtr dwParam2);
```

or:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
static extern uint waveOutMessage(IntPtr deviceID, uint uMsg, ref uint dwParam1, ref uint dwParam2);
```

with a C# method:

```
string GetAudioOutput()
        {
            uint originalDeviceId = 0; //4
            uint newDeviceId = 0; //4
            uint DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET = 0x2015;
            uint DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET = 0x2016;
            int deviceId = 0; //-1

            IntPtr WAVE_MAPPER = new IntPtr(-1);
            uint ret = waveOutMessage(WAVE_MAPPER, DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET, GCHandle.Alloc(originalDeviceId, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject() , GCHandle.Alloc(newDeviceId, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject() );
            //uint ret = waveOutMessage(WAVE_MAPPER, DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET, ref originalDeviceId, ref newDeviceId);
            return deviceId.ToString() + originalDeviceId.ToString() + newDeviceId.ToString() + ret.ToString(); //I get 0000
        }
```

I expect the output of a default audio device ID. But I get 0 (which I've defined) for each variable. I don't have any results with this function on WinServer2012. Did I code something wrong or this is impossible in my case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 is the default device ID

But if you change it in Windows, you will still get 0, but different values in WAVEOUTCAPS with the new device

(you should use Core Audio APIs, more recent and used by Windows)

Sample =>

```
uint nNumDevices = waveOutGetNumDevs();
if (nNumDevices >= 1)
{
    int nRet = MMSYSERR_NODRIVER;
    uint dwFlags = 0;
    uint uWaveID = 0;
    nRet = waveOutMessage((IntPtr)WAVE_MAPPER, DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET, out uWaveID, out dwFlags);
    if (nRet == MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        WAVEOUTCAPS caps = new WAVEOUTCAPS();
        nRet = waveOutGetDevCaps((IntPtr)uWaveID, out caps, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WAVEOUTCAPS)));
    }
}
```

Declarations =>

```
    [DllImport("Winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint waveOutGetNumDevs();

    [DllImport("Winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetDevCaps(IntPtr uDeviceID, out WAVEOUTCAPS pwoc, int cbwoc);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct WAVEOUTCAPS
    {
        public ushort wMid;
        public ushort wPid;
        public uint vDriverVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string szPname;
        public int dwFormats;
        public ushort wChannels;
        public ushort wReserved1;
        public int dwSupport;
    }

    [DllImport("Winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int waveOutMessage(IntPtr deviceID, uint uMsg, out uint dwParam1, out uint dwParam2);

    public const int WAVE_MAPPER = (-1);

    public const int MMSYSERR_BASE = 0;
    /* general error return values */
    public const int MMSYSERR_NOERROR = 0;                    /* no error */
    public const int MMSYSERR_ERROR = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 1);  /* unspecified error */
    public const int MMSYSERR_BADDEVICEID = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 2);  /* device ID out of range */
    public const int MMSYSERR_NOTENABLED = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 3);  /* driver failed enable */
    public const int MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 4);  /* device already allocated */
    public const int MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 5);  /* device handle is invalid */
    public const int MMSYSERR_NODRIVER = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 6);  /* no device driver present */
    public const int MMSYSERR_NOMEM = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 7);  /* memory allocation error */
    public const int MMSYSERR_NOTSUPPORTED = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 8);  /* function isn't supported */
    public const int MMSYSERR_BADERRNUM = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 9);  /* error value out of range */
    public const int MMSYSERR_INVALFLAG = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 10); /* invalid flag passed */
    public const int MMSYSERR_INVALPARAM = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 11); /* invalid parameter passed */
    public const int MMSYSERR_HANDLEBUSY = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 12); /* handle being used simultaneously on another thread (eg callback) */
    public const int MMSYSERR_INVALIDALIAS = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 13); /* specified alias not found */
    public const int MMSYSERR_BADDB = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 14); /* bad registry database */
    public const int MMSYSERR_KEYNOTFOUND = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 15); /* registry key not found */
    public const int MMSYSERR_READERROR = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 16); /* registry read error */
    public const int MMSYSERR_WRITEERROR = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 17); /* registry write error */
    public const int MMSYSERR_DELETEERROR = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 18); /* registry delete error */
    public const int MMSYSERR_VALNOTFOUND = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 19); /* registry value not found */
    public const int MMSYSERR_NODRIVERCB = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 20); /* driver does not call DriverCallback */
    public const int MMSYSERR_MOREDATA = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 21); /* more data to be returned */
    public const int MMSYSERR_LASTERROR = (MMSYSERR_BASE + 21); /* last error in range */

    public const int DRV_RESERVED = 0x0800;

    public const int DRVM_MAPPER = (0x2000);
    public const int DRVM_USER = 0x4000;
    public const int DRVM_MAPPER_STATUS = (DRVM_MAPPER + 0);
    public const int DRVM_MAPPER_RECONFIGURE = (DRVM_MAPPER + 1);
    public const int DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET = (DRVM_MAPPER + 21);
    public const int DRVM_MAPPER_CONSOLEVOICECOM_GET = (DRVM_MAPPER + 23);

    public const int DRV_QUERYDEVNODE = (DRV_RESERVED + 2);
    public const int DRV_QUERYMAPPABLE = (DRV_RESERVED + 5);
    public const int DRV_QUERYMODULE = (DRV_RESERVED + 9);
    public const int DRV_PNPINSTALL = (DRV_RESERVED + 11);
    public const int DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE = (DRV_RESERVED + 12);
    public const int DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACESIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 13);
    public const int DRV_QUERYSTRINGID = (DRV_RESERVED + 14);
    public const int DRV_QUERYSTRINGIDSIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 15);
    public const int DRV_QUERYIDFROMSTRINGID = (DRV_RESERVED + 16);
    public const int DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID = (DRV_RESERVED + 17);
    public const int DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE = (DRV_RESERVED + 18);
    //
    // DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET flags
    //
    public const int DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_FLAGS_PREFERREDONLY = 0x00000001;
```